# Java: How to confirm if a port is open?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, network-programming, port

*I've looked at other posts, but none are this specific. If its a duplicate, mark it as such and I will delete it.*

I am wondering how to confirm if a TCP port is open or not... Obviously, I am creating a socket and calling connect() to the InetAddress and port number specified. My tests show that if the port is not open, there is an IOException thrown, and if the port is open, there is no exception.

Is exception catching the only way to check if the port is open? **Also, perhaps more importantly,** if there is not exception thrown and the line after connect() is executed, does that mean that the entire TCP connection is complete and successful? I am asking because apparently isConnected() does not always return the expected result in some cases, so I'm not sure it is reliable. Do I need to actually read or write something to the port for confirmation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java NIO provides asynchronous socket programming which will return the exception as a parameter which implies that an exception will be thrown if the socket isn't open. This may be preferable if you have a lot of nested calls and are concerned about the size of the stack trace.

The low level (kernel) socket connect function doesn't return until the TCP/IP handshake is completed so you can **assume** the socket is open and ready for use. There is no way to know if the socket is truly open because there could for example be a service outage on the other end of the connection which could prevent the other end from notifying your application that the connection has been closed.  It is therefore possible to know if a connection is closed, if you have received a FIN packet but there is no way to know if it is open. If the connection is made you can assume it is open but short of an application layer handshake there is no way to know if the connection was ever open. Some application layer protocols send frequent no-operation messages to ensure that the socket is still open which helps find out if the connection is closed based on not receiving ACK(nowledgement) that the packet was received within a certain timeout period,  but network lag could in fact cause timeouts to give false-positives. Using a timeout you are assuming it is closed, and after a connect due to the handshake you are assuming it is open, but the only certainty is if you receive a FIN message at the TCP layer the socket is most-certainly closed.

Comment: To what extent does a port scanner complete a handshake? Not sure if I am getting this confused with another technique, but I thought they would send a SYN but never an ACK so it couldn't be viewed as a confirmed connection (to prevent being logged by the server I think).

Comment: There are libraries for Java to open a raw socket, but the purpose of a syn scan is more security related since it is possible with some firewall configurations to determine that the socket is open but blocked by the firewall.  Simply sending a SYN is NOT a completed connection so it wouldn't be possible to send data over that connection.

Comment: Before I mark your answer, just to repeat, there is NO way to confirm a socket/port connection is complete without sending data. But under normal conditions, if there is no exception thrown when calling socket.connect() using the Java sockets class, the port can be presumed as open.

Comment: Once connect returns without error, you can assume the connection is open, or was at least open long enough for it to send SYN/ACK, but the only way to know if the recipient received the ACK to complete the connection is to send some data, once there is an ACK to data you know the port was open on the recipient side.